# Working with emoji in R

Tags: r, emoji

I have a csv file that contains a lot of emoji:

```
Person, Message,
A, ,
A, How are you?,
B,  Alright!,
A,
```

How can I `read.csv()` into R so that the emoji don't become black ?s

(I want to track emoji usage over time )

Comment: Use a font that has emoji.

Comment: @42- So if I have the correct font in R studio I could do something like: 
`data %>%filter(Message == )` ?

Comment: The comma at the end of that two character string might prevent the equality test from succeeding (at least it did when I tried it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My console has a font that accepts those "characters":

```
  txt <- "Person, Message,
 A, ,
 A, How are you?,
 B,  Alright!,
 A, "

 Encoding(txt)
#[1] "UTF-8"
 dput(txt)
#"Person, Message,\nA, \U0001f609,\nA, How are you?,\nB, \U0001f64d Alright!,\nA, \U0001f483\U0001f483"

> tvec <- scan(text=txt, what="")
Read 13 items
> dput(tvec)
c("Person,", "Message,", "A,", "\U0001f609,", "A,", "How", "are", 
"you?,", "B,", "\U0001f64d", "Alright!,", "A,", "\U0001f483\U0001f483"
)

> which(tvec == '\U0001f609,')
[1] 4
```

When I used scan to read that text using a comma sep, then the leading space prevented the equality test from succeeding, but it succeeded if I used the two character version:

```
> which(tvec == '\U0001f609')
integer(0)
> dput(tvec)
c("Person", " Message", "", "A", " \U0001f609", "", "A", " How are you?", 
"", "B", " \U0001f64d Alright!", "", "A", " \U0001f483\U0001f483"
)
> which(tvec == " ")
[1] 5
```

This is with Courier New as the console/editor font on a Mac. To see the explanation for Unicode representations look at `?Quotes` {base}.

Comment: What font is your console using?

Comment: To find out what fonts are used by your console you would using (on a Mac anyway) `quartzFonts()$sans `