# emoji does not render in rstudio console

Tags: r, rstudio, emoji

I am running tests in Rstudio and the output looks like this:

```
> devtools::test()
Loading pkgname
Testing pkgname
<U+221A> | OK F W S | Context
<U+221A> |  2       | test-file.R
```

I am very happy that the tests pass, but the `<U+221A>` suggests that Rstudio is not rendering emojis on my mac. I am running Rstudio Version 1.1.447.

**Edit**

I think this an Rstudio-wide issue. I also see it when rendering markdown.

```
processing file: output.Rmd
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
<U+221A> ggplot2 3.0.0     <U+221A> purrr   0.2.5
<U+221A> tibble  1.4.2     <U+221A> dplyr   0.7.6
<U+221A> tidyr   0.8.1     <U+221A> stringr 1.3.1
<U+221A> readr   1.1.1     <U+221A> forcats 0.3.0
```

Note that I am able to see emoij render in my normal terminal.

[image]

Comment: Do you have examples of where RStudio is successfully rendering Emojis on your Mac? Is it limited to testthat?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328416/working-with-emoji-in-r